# gulp connect-php only looking in root

Tags: php, gulp, browser-sync

I've got a gulp project where I'm using some PHP to pull in patterns to make a styleguide. I've got gulp-connect-php installed and working but it's only running in the ROOT folder and I need it to be looking at whatever is in DIST/

I've got this code here so it uses BrowserSync too

```
gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
  connect.server({}, function(){
    browserSync({
      proxy: 'localhost:8000'
    });
  });
})
```

I've tired `dir` and `baseDir` but neither work.

The full `gulpfile.js` is here

https://gist.github.com/sturobson/9a616c2cbebfc5059bf3

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps the "files" you are looking for:
http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-files

example:

```
   files: [
        'public/**/*',
        'resources/views/**/*'
    ]
```